# Django-REST foreign key object permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have following django models:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', related_name='photos')
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

And IsOwner permission

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners to get it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        return obj.owner == request.user
```

I need to prevent creation of Albums with photos owned by other users. At the moment I using this solution:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        photos = validated_data.pop('photos')

        for _photo in photos:
            ph_obj = Photo.objects.get(id=_photo['id'])
            if self.context['request'].user == ph_obj.owner:
                ph_obj.album = album
                ph_obj.save()
```

But it doesn't feel quite right. Also I think that serializer must raise some kind of exception for this case.
How to perform it?
Thanks.

Comment: What is in `_photo`? Are you only posting the ids of photo or more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom permission for the `AlbumSerializer` to do the check:

```
class CustomerAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'You can only add your photos!'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        if view.action == 'create':
            for photo in request.POST.get('photos'):
                if not Photo.objects.filter(id=photo['id'], owner=request.user).exists():
                    return False
        return True
```

or maybe better with only one db query:

```
class CustomerAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'You can only add your photos!'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        if view.action == 'create':
            user_photos = Photo.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values_list('id', flat=True)
            for photo in request.POST.get('photos'):
                if not photo['id'] in user_photos:
                    return False
        return True
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this method wouldn't work if request.data is serialized in json.

Comment: Why do you think that won't work? At this point request.data or request.POST are aöready python dicts